# website login using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login using curl.
This is the web login form that I'm trying to remote login.

```
 <form id="frmNIDLogin" name="frmNIDLogin" target="_top" autocomplete="off" action="https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login" method="post" onsubmit="return confirmSubmit();">
            <input type="hidden" name="enctp" id="enctp" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="encpw" id="encpw" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="encnm" id="encnm" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="svctype" id="svctype" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="svc" id="svc" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="viewtype" id="viewtype" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="locale" id="locale" value="ko_KR">
            <input type="hidden" name="postDataKey" id="postDataKey" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="smart_LEVEL" id="smart_LEVEL" value="-1">
            <input type="hidden" name="logintp" id="logintp" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="http://www.naver.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="localechange" id="localechange" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="theme_mode" id="theme_mode" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="pre_id" id="pre_id" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="resp" id="resp" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="exp" id="exp" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="ru" id="ru" value="">
            <fieldset class="login_form">
```

and this is the code that i tryied...
how can i send data to original login_check php?(https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login)

```
<?php
$id = $_POST[id];
$pw = $_POST[pw];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'id='.urlencode($id).'&pw='.urlencode($pw));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
echo $page;
?>
```

Comment: you'll need the cookie jar.

Comment: then, how can i apply cookie jar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896893/cookiejar-in-php-curl, cookies maintain login or your session.  Same thing applies when using curl.  The other way it can be done is using and api key setup, where you essentially login on each request.