# Login to Website Using With Google Auth - cURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I can login to Google and get cookies, that's OK but I can not reach my point. I can return to truecaller.com with these cookie (Google Auth cookies). Truecaller has to return 4 cookie files but it returns 3, so I can not get the data which I need. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$USERNAME = 'myusername@gmail.com';
$PASSWORD = 'mypassword';
$COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=alerts&continue=http://www.google.com/alerts/manage');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$formFields = getFormFields($data);

$formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
$formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

$post_string = '';
foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
    $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ('1' == '2') {
    die("Login failed");
    var_dump($result);
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.truecaller.com/auth/google?es=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
    $cookies = array();
    foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $cookie);
        $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
    }
    var_dump($cookies);
}

function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
```

I'm getting these cookies:

```
    '__cfduid' => string 'd1fd776f1b301db9833571daa614d394f1464907495' (length=43)
  'tcSession' => string 'eyJpdiI6IkpQdW1JemFOblRlZE4xTTQyXC9tVVB5WEYyM3poV2lVOUtKV0JOb0NrWG1zPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaktqbGdXNUplOXprVlAyb0Q3ZXJKT0M0NlV1NXVvTkFNNlBMWHhiK2ZCZExrSENoQUhpNDVQWjlaTWJGVVpnenVGdXhjQVJVc0JBWFI2RmpUSmVkcVE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjY5NDc2NDhhYzRmMzBlMzcxYTYwYzJhZjljMDQyMzgwNGE5MTg4ZmIyNTAyY2YzZjYxYzVmNzkyOTE1MWI1OGQifQ==' (length=304)
  'XLBS3' => string 'XLBS1|V1C26|V1C26' (length=17)
```

I also need to get `tcToken` value but I can't. I couldn't find how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the cookie jar of course!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896893/cookiejar-in-php-curl - for the token you probably have to parse it out of the cookie file.  PS it really is called the cookie jar .. lol

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear we need this bit

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);
```

To be like

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

 echo $result; // or file_put_contents( 'cookie.txt', $result );

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);
```

So we can see what the raw data is that is being parsed for the cookies.  Then we can tell if it's missing completely or not being parsed correctly.

Comment: OK, I'll try and let you know about in an hour. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It it's not the same cookie, what's in the actual cookie file, I mean open the file in a text editor to make sure it's being parsed correctly by your code.  If it's in the file then you just need to tweek how the file is being parsed.

Comment: No, it's not base64. I checked it and sure that.  I also tried to use Cookiejar but I think it failed, because I'm getting this error: `Notice: Use of undefined constant COOKIEJAR - assumed 'COOKIEJAR' in /usr/share/nginx/html/thetradersl/two.php on line 14` and  `Notice: Use of undefined constant COOKIEJAR - assumed 'COOKIEJAR' in /usr/share/nginx/html/thetradersl/two.php on line 15`

Comment: There is nothing in the cookies.txt.

Comment: it looks like you are just returning the cookies in the $response, if I read the code correctly.  that line and error is in this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIEJAR);`.  Which you already have too. But if you could get the raw response with the cookies that's what you want to check..

Comment: This line `$result = curl_exec($ch);` just above  `preg_match_all(..)` see what that contains before the preg_match part.  It seems more likely that the RegX is not finding it, then it's the other cookie.

Comment: The `cookie.txt` is empty because you need to put it in these lines `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);`  where it says $cookieFile.  But, its ok because it's in the `$result` variable, we just need to see what's in there so we can tell if the `preg_match_all(..)` part is finding it.  My guess is that this `/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi` needs to be `/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*);/mi` with a `;` at the end, the `[^;]*` is match anything but `;` so without that ending one it's likely eating up too much.

Comment: I made it but it's still empty.

Comment: Just do `echo $result` between `$result = curl_exec($ch);` and `preg_match_all(..)`  It's just putting it in the result and processing it with preg_match_all and a regular expression ( which is fine ).  So we just need to see what the raw data is so we can see if it's not being returned or not being pulled from the result correctly, make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113728/discussion-between-deniz-b-and-artisiticphoenix).